# add-apt-repository failed in k8s docker-in-docker init-container

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-in-docker

In my application, I need to build a docker image on a k8s init-container using docker-in-docker approach.

This is the Dockerfile of the init container:

```
FROM docker-hub-mirror.mycorp.com/docker:dind
ARG username
ARG password
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache bash curl git git-lfs ca-certificates coreutils
RUN git-lfs install
COPY daemon.json /etc/docker/daemon.json
COPY scripts/* /bin/
RUN docker login harbor.mycorp.com -u=${username} -p=${password};\
    sed -i "s/ROBOT_USER/${username}:${password}/g" /bin/build_image.sh
ENV SHOWROOM_LOG_PATH=/var/log/showroom/app.log
ENTRYPOINT ["dockerd-entrypoint.sh"]
```

The flow is to build the input docker image first and use that image to run the application in application containers later.

This is the input Dockerfile:

```
# https://gitlab.com/nvidia/container-images/cuda/-/blob/master/dist/11.7.1/ubuntu2204/devel/cudnn8/Dockerfile
FROM nvidia/cuda:11.7.1-cudnn8-devel-ubuntu22.04
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

WORKDIR /content

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install -y sudo && apt-get install -y python3-pip && pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN apt-get install -y curl gnupg wget htop sudo git git-lfs software-properties-common build-essential libgl1 zip unzip

RUN add-apt-repository ppa:flexiondotorg/nvtop
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install -y nvtop

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x  | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g configurable-http-proxy

ENV PATH="/home/admin/.local/bin:${PATH}"

RUN pip3 install jupyterhub && \
    pip3 install --upgrade notebook && \
    pip3 install oauthenticator && \
    pip3 install pandas scipy matplotlib && \
    pip3 install --upgrade jupyterlab jupyterlab-git && \
    pip3 install ipywidgets && \
    pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio && \
    jupyter lab build
    
RUN jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension

RUN git clone https://github.com/camenduru/jupyter
COPY login.html /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/jupyter_server/templates/login.html

RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos '' admin
RUN adduser admin sudo
RUN echo '%sudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' >> /etc/sudoers

RUN chown -R admin:admin /content
RUN chmod -R 777 /content
RUN chown -R admin:admin /home
RUN chmod -R 777 /home

USER admin

EXPOSE 7860

CMD jupyter-lab --ip 0.0.0.0 --port 7860 --no-browser --allow-root --NotebookApp.token='huggingface' --NotebookApp.tornado_settings="{'headers': {'Content-Security-Policy': 'frame-ancestors *'}}" --NotebookApp.cookie_options="{'SameSite': 'None', 'Secure': True}" --NotebookApp.disable_check_xsrf=True
```

It failed at this line

```
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:flexiondotorg/nvtop
```

At first, I got this error from the init-container logs

```
#0 2.170   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/launchpadlib/launchpad.py", line 230, in __init__
#0 2.170     super(Launchpad, self).__init__(
#0 2.170   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/resource.py", line 472, in __init__
#0 2.170     self._wadl = self._browser.get_wadl_application(self._root_uri)
#0 2.170   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/_browser.py", line 447, in get_wadl_application
#0 2.170     response, content = self._request(url, media_type=wadl_type)
#0 2.170   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/_browser.py", line 389, in _request
#0 2.170     response, content = self._request_and_retry(
#0 2.170   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/_browser.py", line 359, in _request_and_retry
#0 2.170     response, content = self._connection.request(
#0 2.170   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1725, in request
#0 2.171     (response, content) = self._request(
#0 2.171   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/launchpadlib/launchpad.py", line 144, in _request
#0 2.171     response, content = super(LaunchpadOAuthAwareHttp, self)._request(
#0 2.171   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/_browser.py", line 184, in _request
#0 2.171     return super(RestfulHttp, self)._request(
#0 2.171   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1441, in _request
#0 2.171     (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
#0 2.171   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1363, in _conn_request
#0 2.171     conn.connect()
#0 2.171   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1199, in connect
#0 2.172     raise socket_err
#0 2.172   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1153, in connect
#0 2.172     sock.connect((self.host, self.port))
#0 2.172 OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

I've tried two solutions, first is to use the option `--network=host`

I've modified the build step to

```
docker build --network=host -t $tag .
```

then I got this error

```
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/launchpadlib/launchpad.py", line 230, in __init__                                                                                                                                
 super(Launchpad, self).__init__(                                                                                                                                                                                     
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/resource.py", line 472, in __init__                                                                                                                           
 self._wadl = self._browser.get_wadl_application(self._root_uri)                                                                                                                                                      
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/_browser.py", line 447, in get_wadl_application                                                                                                               
 response, content = self._request(url, media_type=wadl_type)                                                                                                                                                         
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/_browser.py", line 389, in _request                                                                                                                           
 response, content = self._request_and_retry(                                                                                                                                                                         
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/_browser.py", line 359, in _request_and_retry                                                                                                                 
 response, content = self._connection.request(                                                                                                                                                                        
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1725, in request                                                                                                                                     
 (response, content) = self._request(                                                                                                                                                                                 
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/launchpadlib/launchpad.py", line 144, in _request                                                                                                                                
 response, content = super(LaunchpadOAuthAwareHttp, self)._request(                                                                                                                                                   
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/_browser.py", line 184, in _request                                                                                                                           
 return super(RestfulHttp, self)._request(                                                                                                                                                                            
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1441, in _request                                                                                                                                    
 (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)                                                                                                                                   
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1363, in _conn_request                                                                                                                               
 conn.connect()                                                                                                                                                                                                       
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1153, in connect                                                                                                                                     
 sock.connect((self.host, self.port))                                                                                                                                                                                 
TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out
```

The second solution is to use `add-host`, I modified the build command to:

```
docker build --add-host dockerhost:`/sbin/ip route|awk '/default/ { print  $3}'` -t $tag .
```

I got the `OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address` like before.

I can build the input Dockerfile locally on my computer, I'm not sure what might be the correct network configuration to make this work on a k8s environment.